# Python ImportError while using youtube-dl by php

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, ssl, xampp

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/youtube-dl", line
>   3, in import youtube_dl File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/*init*.py", line 65, in
>   from .utils import ( File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/utils.py", line 18, in
>   import ssl File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 61, in import _ssl
>   #if we can't import it, let the error propagate ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol
>   GENERAL_NAME_free, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file
>   libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

The Command i used

> youtube-dl --max-quality 2180 --write-thumbnail -x --audio-format mp3
>   -c -o "/home/bahaa/%(id)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFQFMSNZW08&list=RDV-jLo0Ovems

The php code i am using

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFQFMSNZW08&list=RDV-jLo0Ovems';
    //escapeshellarg
    $string = ('youtube-dl --max-quality 2180 --write-thumbnail -x --audio-format mp3 -c -o "/home/bahaa/%(id)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFQFMSNZW08&list=RDV-jLo0Ovems');

    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
        2 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stderr
    );

    $process = proc_open($string, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $ret = proc_close($process);
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'status' => $ret,
            'errors' => str_replace("\n", "<br />", $stderr."<hr />"),
            'output' => $stdout,
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when you invoke `youtube-dl` directly from the command line?

Comment: No i do not it works fine

Answer (score -1):

Hi Finally I got the solution!
Firstly, would you please let me know your server configuration? I'm using XAMPP, in my case, the "Python" and its libs used by Apache are not the same as used by my ubuntu, so I build and install Python3 into /opt/lampp/bin   and  build openssl by myself. You can download openssl1.0.1 from its website and configure it by "./config shared" to build a .so file. 
Next copy the libssl.so* and libcrypto.so* (totally 4 files) into /opt/lampp/lib (this is where LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to) and restart apache now
It works for me, Hope it will help you

Comment: hey, how's your thing going?